# Implementing bcrypt in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: authentication, hash, .net-core, bcrypt

I am new to developing with Core. I created a ASP.NET Core web application (MVC) in Visual Studio with Individual User accounts stored in app. I created a database for the app in SQL server, updated the connection string, and ran Update-Database in the NuGet console. I would like to override the password hashing function and instead use bcrypt to hash. I was hoping to use the BCrypt-Core, BCrypt.Net - Next, or Bcrypt-Official package. But I dont know where to go from there to ensure that the hashing is overridden when the password is generated and when the user logs in.  My guess is that I need to override PasswordHasher but what methods do  I need to override & what about when the user wants to log in? Any advice / suggestions / links to current implementations would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Create a class called BCryptPasswordHasher.cs

```
 public class BCryptPasswordHasher<TUser> : PasswordHasher<TUser> where TUser : class
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Overrides instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordHasher
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="optionsAccessor"></param>
        public BCryptPasswordHasher(IOptions<PasswordHasherOptions> optionsAccessor = null)
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Returns a hashed representation of the supplied password for the specified user.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="user"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override string HashPassword(TUser user, string password)
        {
            return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(password);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordVerificationResult indicating
        //     the result of a password hash comparison.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="user"></param>
        /// <param name="hashedPassword">The hash value for a user's stored password.</param>
        /// <param name="providedPassword"> The password supplied for comparison.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(TUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
        {
            if (hashedPassword == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hashedPassword)); }
            if (providedPassword == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(providedPassword)); }            

            if (BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(providedPassword, hashedPassword))
            {
                return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
            }
        }    
    }
```

In Startup.cs - BEFORE AddIdentity add

```
 services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>, BCryptPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Thanks to Andrew Lock for getting me 90% of the way there. https://andrewlock.net/migrating-passwords-in-asp-net-core-identity-with-a-custom-passwordhasher/